# Why post request accept query string parameters?

Tags: java, http

Spring framework and java servlet accept query string parameters in the post request. How can we accept parameter only in form data while making the REST API with POST method?

Comment: I don't understand the question. HTTP is a text-only protocol.

Comment: Hi, can you add a bit more context on what problem you're facing?

Comment: RFC supports query string parameters for http requests regardless the method.

Comment: Actually I am confused about why post request works like the below example.
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9903?foo=bar"

As I read somewhere that post request is used when we want to send some sensitive data to the server. I just want to know why post request accepts param like this not like below as mandatory.

curl -X POST -d "foo=bar" "http://localhost:9903"

In servlet i am using (request.getParameter("foo")) and in spring boot i am using (@RequestParam).

Comment: So you have a form written in javascript or some other language which has fields in it. Why does the http url accept parameters and how do you stop it from accepting parameters? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Har I want my Rest API (spring boot or servlet) accept param only in form-data. Like in python flask we have request.param("foo"). I want my application does not accept param hi query-string.

Comment: You can send QueryString parameters in both GET and POST.  With a GET, that's the only way to get parameters.  With a POST, it's one of two ways.  You can choose to ignore the QueryString and get the data from the server.